# QueueConnectionFactory look up failed upon below configuration

Tags: tomcat, jms, ibm-mq, jndi

I have configured the below different files for tomcat server, It was working in Weblogic, during migration to tomcat I am not able to use JNDI.

Could you suggest any other option I could check ?

## Code

```
Context ict = new InitialContext();
            Context envctx= (Context) ict.lookup("java:comp/env");
            logger.info("Context : "+envctx); 
                factory = (QueueConnectionFactory) envctx
                        .lookup("jms/JNDI_NAME"); 
                logger.info("Factory : "+factory);
```

## Error

```
QueueConnectionFactory look up failed:: javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance:-javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
```

## Server.xml

```
<Resource name="JNDI_NAME" auth="Container"
                          type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory"                    factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory"
                          HOST="<ip>"
                          PORT="<port>"
                          CHAN="<mqChan>"
                          QMGR="<QueueMag>"/>
```

## Web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jms/JNDI_NAME</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>
```

Comment: I have added more details on the question. @JoshMc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your JNDI name might be what is configured as 'name' in your Server.xml resource. Maybe try this instead:

```
factory = (QueueConnectionFactory) envctx.lookup("JNDI_NAME");
```

Comment: Thanks @axel-podehl

Comment: @RajanPatel if this solved your problem then please accept the answer, if not then please add a comment explaining why.

Comment: I have faced another error `com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI.
The Java(tm) MQI has thrown an exception describing the problem.
See the linked exception for further information.:-com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI.
The Java(tm) MQI has thrown an exception describing the problem.
See the linked exception for further information.
`

Answer (score 0):

After the research, I found that by adding the below block in context XML, it can work instead of the server XML

#### Context xml

```
<Resource
          name="jms/<JNDI_NAME>"
          auth="Container"
          type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory"
          factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory"
          description="JMS Queue Connection Factory for sending messages"
          HOST="<ip>"
          PORT="<port>"
          CHAN="<mqChan>"
          QMGR="<QueueMag> />
  <Resource
          name="jms/remote-sds-input-queue-fjp"
          auth="Container"
          type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue"
          factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueFactory"
          description="JMS Queue for receiving messages from Dialog"
          QU="<QueueName>" />
```